# How to use resolution to show satisfiability

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> How can you use Resolution to show that a set of formulas is satisfiable?

I am confused. If $\Sigma \vdash_{Res} \alpha$ for the resolution then it follows from soundness that $\Sigma \vDash \alpha$ so it must be satisfiable?

Comment: You know about `vDash` but not about `vdash`? That's odd.

Comment: Applying the [Resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resolution_(logic)) procedure to a set $\Sigma$ of formulas, if the *empty clause* cannot be derived and the resolution rule cannot be applied to derive any more new clauses, the original set is *satisfiable*.

Comment: Is this first order logic or propositional logic that we are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

> I am confused. If $\Sigma \vdash_{Res} \alpha$ for the resolution then it follows from soundness that $\Sigma \vDash \alpha$ so it must be satisfiable?

Assuming by 'it' you mean $\Sigma$, then No: that does not follow, regardless of what $\alpha$ is.

OK, here are some things that I hope will help you:

First of all, your reference to $\Sigma \vDash \alpha$ makes me think that so far you have been using Reolsution in the context of proving some kind of logical consequence, e.g. that some statement $\alpha$ follows from some set of statements $\Sigma$.  However, the first thing you do in such a context is to negate the statement $\alpha$, and add it to $\Sigma$, and then let the Reolsution process loose on all those statements (after converting them to clauses). In other words, Resolution really just works with one set of statements.

Second, in Resolution you start with a set of clauses, and that the goal is to keep resolving them until you get an empty clause.  But since the empty clause represents a contradiction, that means that if you are indeed able to derive the empty  clause, then the original set of statements $\Sigma$ is *not* satisfiable.  So, to use Resolution to show that some set of statements $\Sigma$ *is* satisfiable, you must somehow show that it is impossible to derive the empty clause from the clause set as generated from $\Sigma$ ... which requires a kind of meta-argument about the clause set at hand. That is, you can't use Resolution to prove satisfiability .. you can at best show satisfiability by showing how Resolution can't show unsatiasfiability, i.e. it would require a proof *about* Resolution.

Third, in the case of propositional logic, this kind of meta-argument is doable in that you can indeed show that at some point no more new clauses can be generated through resolution, and given that Resolution is complete, that indeed means that the original set of statements is satisfiable.  However, in the case of first-order logic you can easily get in trouble. Indeed, since first-order logic is undecidable, there will be cases where you just can't tell whether you can eventually get the empty clause or not. So while some *specific* set of first-order logic statements may be simple enough for you to conclude that the empty set will never be attained (and thus show that the original set is satisfiable), for others you can't.